# Right Angled Triangle solve knowing the ratio and C

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Equation for a Right Angled Triangle

$C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$

If you know $C$

$C = 49$

And you know the ratio of width to height

$16:9$

Is it possible to work out $A$ and $B$ or will there be too many answers. I can't imagine there will be because the ratio makes it pretty strict.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, let $A > B$

Then the ratio implies that $9A = 16B\implies A=\frac{16}{9}B$

Substituting this in:

$$49=\sqrt{(\frac{16}{9}B)^2+B^2} = B\sqrt{\frac{337}{81}} $$

$$B = \frac{49\cdot 9}{\sqrt{337}} = \frac{441}{\sqrt{337}}$$

Then $A = \frac{784}{\sqrt{337}}$

Answer (score 0):

The legs are 16k and 9k for some positive constant k.

Then, $(16k)^2 + (9k)^2 = 49^2$

From which, the value of k can be found. Hence, the lengths of the legs can also be found.

Comment: See, I thought it was pretty simple.....

Comment: @CallumLinington Glad to learn that.

Comment: if you sqrt the 16k and 9K would that just equal 49...

Comment: @CallumLinington No. $16k)^2 + (9k)^2 = 49^2$ does not mean  $16k + 9k = 49$. However, if $(16k)^2 \times (9k)^2=49^2$, then $(16k)(9k)=49$.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see,

$C^2=A^2+B^2$

It means C is largest side and equal to 49. And two sides A and B are in ratio 16:9.

Let A=16x, B=9x.

Put value of A, B and C to find values.